# How to match multiple element tags with single XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

```
<a data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;T&quot;}" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/hovercard.php?id=1063783263698960&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22on_public_ufi%22%3Atrue%2C%22hc_location%22%3A%22ufi%22%7D" href="https://www.facebook.com/aslanneferler.org/?rc=p" class="img _8o _8s UFIImageBlockImage" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-controls="js_23b" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_23c" id="js_23d"><img alt="Aslan Neferler Tim" class="img UFIActorImage _54ru img" src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p32x32/16649279_1243625492381402_3963550962824882029_n.jpg?oh=7b12626e660bc99add267af31ed0c47e&amp;oe=59E2A54C"></a>


<img alt="Abdurrezzak Taşkın" class="img UFIActorImage _54ru img _8o _8s UFIImageBlockImage img" src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p32x32/18838939_1832790993710312_8699687160338170698_n.jpg?oh=0f627688abff94244dce906bd99dc56b&amp;oe=59A4A24B">
```

How can I select two of the tags you have seen above? I want to select 10 elements in total in one "a tagged", nine "img tagged" in total.

I wrote the following lines of code. But I did not get the result I wanted. What do you recommend. I want to do this using Selenium in Python.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                    '//img[@class="img UFIActorImage _54ru img _8o _8s UFIImageBlockImage img"]') or driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_kq"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below xpath for the same and let me know if any issue

```
//a[@id='js_23d'] | //img[@class='img UFIActorImage _54ru img _8o _8s UFIImageBlockImage img']
```

Comment: I have not had a problem so far. Thank you so much. Good day, good work :)

Comment: @DavutDURGUN, If this solution is helpful to you then don't forget to `accept` the answer :)